# Redirect to diffrent action when reciving json results in my script

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

i'm getting a list view json results and I would like to redirect to a different view and display the results according to my json 
( I hope i'm clear) this what i'm did

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#term").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               $.ajax({
                   url: "Home/GetSubjectsName",
                   data: "{'term': '" + request.term + "' }",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   type: "POST",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                   success: function (data) {
                       response($.map(data, function (item) {
                           return {
                               label: item.value,
                               value: item.value,
                               id: item.id,
                           }
                           var url = '@Url.Action("bla", "blaaaa")';
                       }))
                   }
               });
           },
           minLength: 2,
       });
   });
```

my jsonlook like this :

```
 public JsonResult GetSubjectsName(string term)
    {
        var results = db.subjects.Where(s => term == null ||
        s.SubjectName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Select(x => new
        { id = x.SubjectId, value = x.SubjectName }).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and the action  I would like to display the results is this (instead of partial view)

public ActionResult bla(string term)
        {
            IEnumerable serach = from sub in db.subjects.Where(t => t.SubjectName.Contains(term)).Distinct()
                                                         select new SearchResultsViewModel
                                                         {

```
                                                         Created = sub.Created,
                                                         Gender = sub.Gender,
                                                         OccupationDecription = sub.OccupationDecription,
                                                         Image = sub.Image,
                                                         SubjectName = sub.SubjectName
                                                     };


        ViewBag.term = term;

        return RedirectToAction("bla", "home", serach.ToList());
    }
```

my View :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProJect.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel>
```

foreach ....

what I need is to go to a different action and display the data

Comment: In the server side I would return a redirect to another action that would represent the result.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'go to a different action'?

Comment: There is no point making an ajax call and then redirecting. Just do a normal submit and redirect in the POST method

Comment: I understand that i'm not clear , I just don't knowhow to attach all this loss ends (I added the controller part)

Comment: You're simply setting the source for the autocomplete with this ajax request. Why would you need to redirect if you're just trying to populate a plugin's list of "suggestions" to the user?

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I need it to be a autocomplete in my search

Comment: Then once you have selected the value, submit the form and the redirect in the controller.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the "source" property does. You need to handle the submission of the form separately from you're autocomplete setup.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  , yes true ,i'm not sure how to do it

Comment: What is it you want to display in the other form? (the code in your `bla()` method just seems to be repeating what you have already done in the `GetSubjectsName()` method). Hard to understand what your trying to display.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that might help. Your post is still a bit unclear, so I'm filling in the missing pieces according to what you have described. I've made no attempt at designing the form layout.

Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@using( Html.BeginForm("bla") ) {
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.term)
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.term)
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#term").autocomplete({ source: '@Url.Action("GetSubjectsName")', autoFocus: true, minLength: 2 });

});
</script>
```

Your autocomplete should be changed to:

```
public JsonResult GetSubjectsName(string term)
{
    return Json(db.subjects
     .Where(s => term == null ||
         s.SubjectName.ToLower()
        .Contains(term.ToLower()))
     .OrderBy(x => x.SubjectName)
     .Select(x => x.SubjectName)
     .Distinct(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As far as I can tell, everything else should work as intended.